# Issue with Tap interface and routing

Tags: iptables, tap

I am getting stuck in a bit of a rut and not sure if it's a limitation with EC2 servers, my attempts to get it working or a limitation with Softether.

I have an EC2 server with 2 NICs; eth0 and eth1. Each NIC is mapped to a public IP address. Softether is running on the server. I am trying to create an environment where one login (user1) goes out via eth0 and given the public IP assigned to that NIC, for another user (user2) I want to send traffic out via eth1 and the public IP mapped to that.

I am using secureNAT for user1 and that all works successfully. For user2, I have turned off secureNAT and linked the hub to a local bridge device called tap_secondary. I can connect to the internet via both ethernet interfaces so I know they can see the internet.

I've then allocated an ip address of 10.10.11.1/24 to tap_secondary. I'm using dnsmasq to assign IP addresses from this. I can successfully log into the VPN server and user2 is given an IP address from the 10.10.11.0/24 range.

From the linux server I can ping the 10.10.11.xx address allocated to user2 but if I ping using the source IP of eth1 this fails. I've tried numerous guides on IP tables to send traffic from the TAP to eth1 but nothing seems to work successfully. I also cannot ping addresses on the internet from 10.10.11.1 (the ip allocated to tap_secondary).

What's not clear is whether the above should work, whether my IP tables are just not right, whether ec2 supports this and I just seem to be going around in circles.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Many thanks,
Dean

Comment: How do you distinguish the setup between both "users"? What happens when both "users" log in? Would it help to just make a network namespace, move one NIC to that namespace, and make sure that everything which should use that NIC always runs in that namespace?

Comment: @dirkt each user is created a in separate hub in Softether - we'll call them hub1 (user1 is held in here) and hub2 (user2) is held in here.

User1 connects to the VPN and correctly routes out of eth0 as expected. I am using the built in secureNAT feature of Softether for this. Hub2 has secureNAT turned off and is bound to the tap interface using the local bridge feature. 

dnsmasq successfully provides an IP address but just doesn't seem to want to route out via eth1.

I've not tested using namespaces so will have a read and see if this will help. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If `eth0` and `eth1` are bridge slaves/ports of different bridges, would it be enough to just block L3 forwarding between the two bridges?